# Find maximum difference in an array along with the positions of the elements in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Consider an array - `arr = {2, 3, 10, 6, 4, 8, 1}`
I have written the code to find the maximum difference between `arr[j]` and `arr[i]` such that `j > i`. In this case. 10 - 2 = 8.

```
        int max_diff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
        int min_element = arr[0]; 
        int i; 
        for (i = 1; i < arr_size; i++)  
        { 
            if (arr[i] - min_element > max_diff) 
                max_diff = arr[i] - min_element; 
            if (arr[i] < min_element) 
                min_element = arr[i]; 
        }
```

I would also like to get the actual elements or their positions that resulted in this difference (number 10 and number 2 in this case) so I modified my code as follows -

```
    int max_diff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
    int min_element = arr[0]; 
    int max_element = 0; 
    int i; 
    for (i = 1; i < arr_size; i++)  
    { 
        if (arr[i] - min_element > max_diff) {
            max_diff = arr[i] - min_element; 
            max_element = arr[i] // New Addition. This part works
        }
        if (arr[i] < min_element) 
            min_element = arr[i]; 
    }
```

I am able to find the value of the biggest number (number 10), but cant figure out how to find the smallest number (number 2). `min_element` variable holds the value of the lowest number in the array (number 1) and not the lowest number that resulted in the difference.

Help!

Comment: should not be the answer is : 10-1=9 ? maxPos=2-> 10 and minPosition=6->1 ?

Comment: Sadly, I don't understand the problem. Where `arr[j]` available ?

Comment: I updated the question. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have your solution

You'll want to set min_element or a new variable, maybe min_element_in_max_difference, where you're already setting max_element.

```
    int max_diff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
int min_element = arr[0]; 
int max_element = 0; 
int min_element_in_max_difference = 0;
int i; 
for (i = 1; i < arr_size; i++)  
{ 
    if (arr[i] - min_element > max_diff) {
        max_diff = arr[i] - min_element; 
        max_element = arr[i] // New Addition. This part works
        min_element_in_max_difference = min_element; //Newer Addition. Should work!
    }
    if (arr[i] < min_element) 
        min_element = arr[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly you want to know the max difference of arr[j] and arr[i] where arr[j] > arr[i] and I think what should have been clarified in the question is that j > i so that 1 would not be an option for the min element. The problem is that the code finds the minimum array element when it needs to find the minimum array element used during the max subtraction. A simple boolean to track the max subtraction should suffice.

```
   int max_diff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
    int min_element = arr[0]; 
    int max_element = 0; 
    int i; 

    boolean newSubtractor = false;

    for (i = 1; i < arr_size; i++)  
    { 

        newSubtractor = false;

        if (arr[i] - min_element > max_diff) {
            max_diff = arr[i] - min_element; 
            max_element = arr[i] // New Addition. This part works
            newSubtractor = true;
        }
        if (arr[i] < min_element && newSubtractor) 
            min_element = arr[i]; 
    }
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Question has been updated

Answer (score -1):

It would better to sort the array first by the ascending order or descending order.
Get the difference between first and last element.

I hope this will find you well.

Comment: Incase of sort he will lost the position of corresponding element.